# .string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my .net app i add guest parameters are guest_id,first_name,email_address,phone_number

i also create a procedures of addguest and view then when i debug the error is shows is input string is not in corret format in 2nd line

```
public class Class1
{
    public bool addguest(int guest_id, string first_name, string Email_address, int Phone_number)
    {
        try
        {
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("sed");
            db.ExecuteDataSet("addguest", new object[] { guest_id, first_name, Email_address, Phone_number });
            return tr
```

and classlibrary work is

```
public class Class1
{
    public bool addguest(int guest_id, string first_name, string Email_address, int Phone_number)
    {
        try
        {
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("sed");
            db.ExecuteDataSet("addguest", new object[] { guest_id, first_name, Email_address, Phone_number });
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public DataTable show()
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("sed");
       return db.ExecuteDataSet("view").Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: my quetions is that how i reslove this error

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug ,inspect the values of Guest_Id ans Phone_Number variables and check if it is a valid int value.

Comment: yess in database it is int in guestid and phone number...

Answer (score 1):

telephone number at least seven digits.  why dont you store the phone number in string? there is no point to store phone number in int. and I am not sure if int can store 7 digits

Comment: i done this...but error is coming "Input string is not in correct format"